# Can I use response in if () in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I try to create kotlin app with OkHttp3. Can I use `response.header("error")` or `response.header("success")` in `if()`?
For example, if I got response with error I will show error or if I get `success` and I can start next activity to show in next activity `header("username")`.
My request fun:

```
fun requestAuth(url: String) {
        var param = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("login", login.text.toString())
            .add("password", password.text.toString())
            .build()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(param).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
//                startActivity(Intent(this@Login, NavigationMenu::class.java)
//                    .putExtra("session_token", response
//                        .header("session_token")
//                        .toString())
                      .putExtra("username", response.header("username").toString()))
            }
```

Thank you for every suggestion

Comment: What do you mean? You want to distinguish between a successful and erroneous response in your on Response callback?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to distinguish between a successful and erroneous response in your on Response callback?

Comment: Yes, I want to distinguish response

Comment: and pass different information between activities if it is possible